# Can multiple tables be encoded in one FlatBuffers buffer?

Tags: go, flatbuffers

Can multiple tables be encoded in one FlatBuffers buffer?

I may be attempting the impossible. If anyone can set me straight I would very much appreciate it.

I have multiple unrelated tables. That is, each one is completely separate, and not included in another table in the same schema.

In all my testing, only the FINAL table retrieves correctly from the buffer.

I suspect that builder.Finish() can be called only ONCE during the entire encoding process, and not after EACH table has been encoded.

Answer (score 1):

No, each buffer has only one root. But you can easily define a wrapper table that contains both tables, of course.